# Pattern matching tuples as inputs to pure function

Tags: pattern-matching, pure-function

I've been having an issue with functions which are supposed to receive as input a list of tuples.
My troubles are two-fold:

1. The function doesn't properly identify the pattern test I laid out in the definition of the inputs.
2. The pattern matching itself is not ideal for a list of (same length) tuples and I couldn't find a more suitable pattern to match for.

My issue was originally in a very convoluted function, but I managed to replicate it in a simpler form.

```
g[x_, {a_, b_}] := a x^b (*generic function - actual definition of G is irrelevant other than the input structure*)
SetAttributes[myfun, HoldFirst]
myfun[f_[args__, pars:{__}], x_ : {{__} ..}] := f[Sequence @@ #, pars] & /@ x
```

First I check to see if my pattern matches what I want it to do (more or less as it still doesn't properly identify tuples of different lengths).

```
In[58]:= MatchQ[Tuples[Range@10,1],{{__}..}]
MatchQ[Range@10,{{__}..}]
MatchQ[x,{{__}..}]

Out[58]= True

Out[59]= False

Out[60]= False
```

Note that a simple Range doesn't trigger the pattern match and neither does a generic symbol x (The symbol returns a weird output which I just noticed after posting this question - the function is not applied and yet the symbol is returned).
Despite this:

```
In[68]:= myfun[g[x, {a, b}], Range[2, 4]] (*Regular range*)
myfun[g[x, {a, b}],Tuples[ Range[2, 4],1]] (*Properly formatted tuples*)
myfun[g[x,{a,b}],x] (*Symbol (!) - still works*)

Out[68]= {2^b a,3^b a,4^b a}

Out[69]= {2^b a,3^b a,4^b a}

Out[70]= x
```

My only conclusion is that for some reason the function does not evaluate the condition I set. Were I a betting man, my money is likely on problematic syntax.
Also, if there is a better way to match a list of tuples I would appreciate the insight.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to match a list of lists that are all the same length, why not just use `x_List?MatrixQ`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, My understanding of pattern matching syntax in pure function input is a little lacking and not well formed. Is there a good reference for it? I haven't found much by way of the documentation.

Comment: I'd recommend starting [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html#1615). The `?` syntax ([PatternTest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)) is explained a little further down.

Comment: Your suggestion was very helpful!
Thank you for the reference as well, I will make sure to read further into this subject.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out one of my issues on my own and figured I would update this question in case others happen upon it.

I had a syntactic error in the definition of my function.

Instead of

```
myfun[f_[args__, pars:{__}], x_ : {{__} ..}]
```

I should have written

```
myfun[f_[args__, pars:{__}], x : {{__} ..}]
```

Note the underscore near the x input. I still don't have a better way to identify tuples.

Comment: So does `x : {{_, _}..}` do what you want better?

Answer (score 1):

This expression

```
x_ : {{__} ..}
```

is actually an `Optional`. It's a way to give a default value to an argument. We can demonstrate what it does with this:

```
myfun[g[x, {a, b}]]
(* {{a*__^b}} *)
```

So, it's equivalent to this:

```
myfun[g[x, {a, b}], {{__} ..}]
```

Now, since you always passed in a second argument, it's not the default value that is causing problems. It's just that you actually didn't provide a constraint on that second argument in terms of pattern matching. The only constraint that the argument is required to match is `x_` (the bit before the colon). So anything is allowed to match. It's perhaps unfortunate that the colon is used for both `Pattern` and `Optional`, because it leads to these kinds of masking problems.

As you already discovered, the solution is to just remove the underscore after the `x`, which results in the colon being parsed as `Pattern` rather than `Optional`.

While it's not directly related to your question, and so maybe not applicable to your real computations (I know `g` was just a dummy example), I feel compelled to comment on your design. If we look at this:

```
myfun[f_[args__, pars : {__}], x : {{__} ..}] := f[Sequence @@ #, pars] & /@ x
```

we notice that `args` is never referenced on the right hand side. There are times when you want to do this, just match a pattern but not use the actual values, and in those situations you don't have to give the pattern a name:

```
    myfun[f_[__, pars : {__}], x : {{__} ..}] := f[Sequence @@ #, pars] & /@ x
```

However, in this case, that seems inadvisable. The reason why you needed to set the `HoldFirst` attribute was so that `g[x, {a, b}]` didn't get evaluated, which it otherwise would since it matches that pattern for `g`. In other words, you're manually constructing a `g`-headed expression that would normally evaluate directly as an argument to `myfun`. Consequently, you must not be retrieving any `g`-headed expressions elsewhere and passing them to `myfun`, because then they'd be evaluated before `myfun` and `myfun` wouldn't work properly. So, you're manually creating dummy values for `g`'s first argument (that you will throw away) just to match a pattern. That's not a reason to use unnamed patterns.

A better strategy would look something like this:

```
myfunAlt[func_, pars : {__}, x : {{__} ..}] := func[Sequence @@ #, pars] & /@ x
```

Now, there are improvements we could make to that, but since we don't know your "real" `g` or anything about your context, I won't speculate on next steps.